# Increment ID Number (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, drop-down-menu

I'm using jQuery Selectbox plugin which has this function:

```
function setupContainer(options) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    $container = $(container);
    $container.attr('id', elm_id+'_container');
    $container.addClass(options.containerClass);

    return $container;
}
```

... it applies the same ID name to all dropdowns, how do I modify the above code so each id is numbered (starting from 1) and unique?

View the full script [here](http://pastebin.com/d3d839161).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store elm_id as a property of your function like this

```
function setupContainer(options) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    $container = $(container);

    var elm_id = setupContainer.uid++;

    $container.attr('id', elm_id+'_container');
    $container.addClass(options.containerClass);

    return $container;
}
setupContainer.uid = 1;
```

This way you don't rely on another global variable.

Answer (score 0):

i'm presuming elm_id is a number and it's a global variable.If so the code would look like this:

```
function setupContainer(options) {
var container = document.createElement("div");
$container = $(container);
elm_id++;
$container.attr('id', elm_id+'_container');
$container.addClass(options.containerClass);

return $container;
```

}